# Capture Screen When Core Animation Is Happening

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, core-animation

I know I can capture the screen using the following code:

```
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
  [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But how can I capture the screen when a core animation is happening.

When the view is animating, the screenshot is its final position but not the position the customer is seeing.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Kai.

Answer (score 0):

You are using view.layer, try to replace with [view.layer presentationLayer] which represent the current frame from the animation.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a timer to take multiple screenshots during the animation.

Comment: The problem is that whenever we capture the image, it does not show the animated part but shows the whole shape or text or whatever the thing is animating on its original place and shape.